# Record MMS Video stream using .NET

Tags: c#, video, streaming, capture

I want to record MMS and RTMP streams using .NET. Can anyone give some sample code snippet.

I have aleady tried VLC Sout, its not much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool, Mencoder which comes as part of ffmpeg tool, its a great tool and works perfect.

Comment: And how do we can use it in C#? Can we reference to this DLL?